# How to prevent multi-taps in android apps

Tags: android

I use onTouch as it is the best and more modifiable than for an instance onClick. It is a custom view that is being touched that I want to respond with action, and I have allready limited so you can't just touch and it does it over and over. Now I need it to limit the amount of simountanious taps.

EDIT:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    lines++;

    return false;
}
```

I have prevented constant action, but not the possibility to press with more than 1 finger, so that if you tap with more the rest of the fingers get ignored

Comment: post what you have done so far.

Comment: What I have so far simply prevents an infinite loop(constant action on press)

Comment: You need to have a background thread like handler to check onTouch event for a particular time. If touch is not happening then you can reset the timer. If touch is happening then limit the on touch event to how much you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.
best for you may be limit it inside in your overrided `onTouch` event.

```
if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
    System.out.println("Multitouch detected!");
    return true;
}
else
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
```

Another option is set attribute `android:splitMotionEvents = false` in your xml file.

Comment: By returning true after it detects multitouch, it will still cause an infinite loop. The tricky part is to prevent touch with more than 1 finger and yet stopping action after the tap

Comment: A better way to say it might be allow any touch that is below an allowed number and ignoring the rest